# How to get the attributes inside a tag in an html file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

Here is my link i want to extract the youtube videos out from the html at this URL

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mizzoushape/uploads?orderby=updated

$<link rel ='alternate' href='somelink.html'/>$
```

Can any one help me out how to fetch the attributes inside the tag..

Thanks in advance for your valuable time

Comment: <code><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfuZ6EFsD-M&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/></code> this is my piece of code to parse

Answer (score 1):

**If you are parsing XML File Then:**

In the parser:didStartElement method, the attributes are stored in the attributeDict dictionary. The values are then stores with the attribute name as the key

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

// Here you can get value from "attributeDict" by key for example
NSString *strHref = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];

}
```